# Not able to import @/screens/AreaChartScreen/chartAdds in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

I want to add Dots in my react native Line Chart component.
I have installed react-native-svg and react-native-svg-charts.
I need to import Dots, Line, Gradient from '@/screens/AreaChartScreen/chartAdds' but the import statement does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably are your babel and jsonconfig configurations that are wrong; the configuration is more tricky than with next/react.

I saw this video and may help you.

https://youtu.be/03F0xzI9VnU :)